# Understanding class members behavior Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to understand, what actually happens when we initiate an instance of a child class.

```
public class A { 
2.      public int x, y; 
3.      public A () { x=1; y=2; }
4.      public int getx () { return x; }
5.  }
6.  public class B extends A { 
7.      public int x, z; 
8.      public B () { super(); x=3; y=4; z=5; }
9.      public int getx () { return x; } 
10.     public int getz () { return z; } 
11. }
12. public class Prob1 { 
13.     public static void main (String[] args){
14.         A o1 = new A(); 
15.         A o2 = new B(); 
16.         B o3 = new B();
17.         System.out.println(o1.x);     
18.         System.out.println(o1.getx()); 
19.         System.out.println(o1.y); 
20.         System.out.println(o1.getz()); 
21.         System.out.println(o2.x); 
22.         System.out.println(o2.getx());
23.         System.out.println(o2.y);
```

I would love to here a detailed explanation of what is going on here exactly, but the main thing I can't understand is why line '21' prints the number 1, and line '23' prints the number 4.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i does not compile: `o1.getz()` - cannot find symbol `getz()` of variable `o1` of type `A`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymorphism applies to methods, not to instance variables.

Both lines 21 and 23 print the value of the instance variables of class `A`, since that's the compile time type of `o2` (even though its runtime type is `B`).

```
21. System.out.println(o2.x);
```

The value of `A`'s `x` member is `1` (set by the constructor `public A () { x=1; y=2; }`).

```
23. System.out.println(o2.y);
```

The value of `A`'s `y` member is `4` (set by the constructor `public B () { super(); x=3; y=4; z=5; }`).

Note the `B` has an `x` instance variable that hides `A`'s variable of the same name. Therefore `B`'s constructor doesn't change `A`'s `x` variable to `3`. On the other hand, `B` doesn't have a `y` instance variable, so `y=4;` changes the value of `A`'s `y` variable to `4`.

BTW, line 20 has a compilation error. I had to comment it out in order to execute your code.

Also note that `o2.getx()` gives a different result than `o2.x`, since `getx()` is a method overridden by class `B`, so it returns `B`'s instance variable `x`, whose value is `3` (since the runtime type of `o2` is `B`).